# Regular expression to identify java function

Tags: java, regex, grammar

I am trying to identify a java function block addition  in a diff file (new line start with `+` in diff).
For that I am using regular expression.

It is working fine, however I need to identify all (if not, at least maximum) possible combinations of keyword used in java method declarations.

Here is my regular expression written in my java program

```
Pattern functionPatter = Pattern.compile("\\+\\s*(public|private|protected)?(\\s+static)?(\\s+final)?\\s+\\w+\\s+\\w+\\s*\\(.*?\\)\\s*(throws .*)+\\{.*\\}",Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Please suggest me if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what you are trying to match with `\\s+\\w+\\s+\\w+\\s*`.  If you are looking for a return type, then that won't do at all.

It appears that you are trying to match the function body using `\\{.*\\}`.  That won't work, because braces may be nested, and regular expressions cannot handle nesting.

[Modifier keywords can appear in any order, and you are missing a few](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10299123/1157100), such as:

- `synchronized`
- `transient`
- `volatile`
- `strictfp`

If you want to implement this correctly, don't just make assumptions based on code that you have been seeing.  Read the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/).

Answer (score 1):

For the java spec there are already complete parsers based e.g. on **JavaCC** or **Antlr**. IMHO the safest way would be process a java file using one of those and extracting the methods from there. Processing using regular expressions is quite difficult, e.g. how about methods in comments.

https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java8

Comment: or methods as String value `String m = "public static void main()";`